# Update existing, latest entry to websql database

Tags: javascript, sql-update, web-sql

im trying to insert a value into an existing row in a websql database, however everything i've tried so far seems to be without luck.

Table Creation:

```
function createDB(t) {
     t.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WALKS (id integer primary key autoincrement, Distance TEXT, Duration TEXT, PathCoordinates TEXT, Images TEXT, WalkTitle Text, Description Text)');
}
```

The following statement should occur on the click of a button, however i suspect the statement is incorrect as im getting no errors?

```
var walkTitle = document.getElementById("walkTitle").value;

db.transaction(function(t) {
     t.executeSql('Update WALKS SET WalkTitle=? WHERE id(SELECT MAX(id)', [walkTitle]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, many things could go wrong, so first of all you should add success/error callbacks to `executeSQL`, so you can pin down the problem:

```
t.executeSql('<sql>', [args], function (t, results) {
       console.log('ok');
   }, function(t, error) {
       console.log(error: ' + error.message);
   });
```

My guess is that your update SQL is wrong, I think it should be more like:

```
Update WALKS SET WalkTitle=? WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) from WALKS)
```

Another thing is that your code won't do anything if you don't have at least one row there already in the table. Or `walkTitle` could be null/undefined. Or thousand of other reasons, but error callback (and error.message) should point you in the right direction.